# SQLite: how to isolate WHERE clause to only one dataset in a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause

I have a database with dated entries of customers, type of customer. Some make a purchase, some don't.

Table looks like this:

```
DATE|sessionID|customer_type|purchase value|
```

I'm trying to create a table that computes what is the total amount of customers, total amount of customers that make a purchase, and to sort it by customer type and date (weekly).

**Code**

```
CREATE TABLE KPIs (

'week' integer,

'customer_type' integer,

'customer_traffic' integer,

'customer_that_purchased' integer
);

INSERT INTO KPIs (

week, 

customer_type, 

customer_traffic, 

customer_that_purchased)

SELECT 

week, 

customer_type_var, 

count(session_id), 

count(purchase_value) 

FROM data 

WHERE purchase_value <> 0 

GROUP BY week, traffic_type_var ;
```

The problem when I do this is that the WHERE clause applies to both counting total customers and customers having made a purchase, which is obviously incorrect (it should only apply to counting customers having made a purchase).

How can I SELECT multiple data sets and have WHERE clauses only applying to some data sets and not others?

Comment: UNION two selects

Comment: hi Kris, could you elaborate a bit more on this? I UNION'ed two SELECTS but because columns on the left and right need to be the same number, I can't fill the KPI table.

Comment: So you make the columns match, shouldn't be a big problem. unfortunately I don't have time to setup a database and show you how. perhaps if you provide a database.

Answer (score 0):

Consider conditional aggregation by moving previous `WHERE` clause into a `sum` expression:

```
INSERT INTO KPIs (week, customer_type, customer_traffic, customer_that_purchased)    
SELECT week, customer_type_var, 
       count(session_id), 
       sum(purchase_value <> 0)
FROM data 
GROUP BY week, customer_type_var;
```

Comment: Hi Parfait, thanks but count(session_id) is returning the same numbers than sum(purchase_value <> 0), meaning the two columns are identical. I don't understand why count(session_id) is computing with the same condition than sum(purchase_value)?

Comment: Consider checking your data. As shown in [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ea48d/2/0), this solution should work.

Comment: Hi Parfait, what I mean is that when I type the following:
INSERT INTO KPIs (week, customer_type, customer_traffic, customer_that_purchased)
SELECT week, customer_type_var, count(session_id), (SELECT count(purchase_value) FROM data WHERE clickout_rev <> 0) 
FROM DATA
GROUP BY week, traffic_type_child

The customer_that_purchased column is just the repeat of the same first value. It doesn't compute for each week and each customer type like it did for session_id. This is what I can't fix. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Wait. There is no subquery in this solution. I have no inner `SELECT`. And of course value repeats as your subquery is not correlated to outer query. Please advise why this answer does not work.